# Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/i18n/Translation-en

Tags: 16.04, apt, update-manager

I am getting below error on sudo apt-get update.

```
sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease                 
Hit:2 https://repo.skype.com/deb unstable InRelease                                                                                             
Hit:3 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease                                                                      
Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                              
Hit:5 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt xenial-pgdg InRelease                                                       
Hit:6 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x xenial InRelease                                                                
Hit:7 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                        
Hit:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                          
Hit:9 https://ftp.ussg.iu.edu/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ InRelease    
Hit:12 https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./ InRelease
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-2/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease [17.5 kB]
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en                                                              
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages                                                              
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages                                                              
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages                                                               
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages                                                               
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en                                                              
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en                                                              
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Err:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ppa.launchpad.net_webupd8team_java_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_i18n_Translation-en.xz - open (13: Permission denied)
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Fetched 17.5 kB in 39s (446 B/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/i18n/Translation-en  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ppa.launchpad.net_webupd8team_java_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_i18n_Translation-en.xz - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

A quick help will highly be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have a file that has invalid permissions that can be removed:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ppa.launchpad.net_webupd8team_java_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_i18n_Translation-en.xz
```

You can also run this command to clear the apt cache:

```
sudo apt clean
```

After that your `apt update` command should work as expected.